# string.Format of a timer?

Tags: c#

I've a time ticker event, I want to write it to a label in format ( hours:minutes:seconds 00:00:00 ) it does not print the 0 values! it shows like ::1 when starts to count... what to do? Solved, thanks for all replies

```
private void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            seconds++;
            if(seconds == 59)
            {
                minutes++;
                seconds = 0;
            }
            if(minutes == 59)
            {
                hours++;
                minutes = 0;
            }

            this.label1.Text = string.Format("{0:##}:{1:##}:{2:##}", hours, minutes, seconds);
        }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A better method is using DateTime and TimeSpan objects. For example:

```
DataTime start = <set this somehow>

void timer_Tick(...)
{
   var elapsed = DateTime.Now - start;

   label1.Text = string.Format("{0:HH:mm:ss}", elapsed);
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Best would be to use TimeSpan and DateTime as others have said. If you want to continue using your current method, though, change the format string to:

```
string.Format("{0:00}:{1:00}:{2:00}", hours, minutes, seconds)
```

The `00` format will cause two digits to always be printed, even zeroes.

Answer (score 3):

Try a thought experiment - set seconds and minutes to 58, and walk through your code and see what happens...

Answer (score 2):

Use a ***[TimeSpan](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/269ew577.aspx)***